# Converting json string of Intent to object of Intent giving exception

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent, gson

I am using Gson class to convert JSON string data to [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) object. But I am getting exception.

JSON string of Intent:

```
{
   "targetIntent":{
      "mAction":"android.intent.action.VIEW",
      "mData":{
         "authority":{
            "decoded":"com.android.contacts",
            "encoded":"com.android.contacts"
         },
         "fragment":{

         },
         "path":{
            "decoded":"NOT CACHED",
            "encoded":"/contacts/lookup/1471i541ce89b89ad6a59"
         },
         "query":{

         },
         "scheme":"content",
         "uriString":"NOT CACHED",
         "host":"NOT CACHED",
         "port":-2
      },
      "mFlags":0
   }
}
```

Conversion code:

```
Intent targetIntent =
    gson.fromJson(histroyDataObject.getString("targetIntent"), Intent.class);
```

This gives exception:

```
Cause: Instantiation Exception
Detail Message: Failed to invoke private android.net.Uri() with no args
```

Stack trace:

```
08-31 01:08:19.045: W/System.err(290): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: android.net.Uri
08-31 01:08:19.065: W/System.err(290):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-31 01:08:19.065: W/System.err(290):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
08-31 01:08:19.065: W/System.err(290):  at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$2.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:91)
08-31 01:08:19.076: W/System.err(290):  ... 24 more
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The "json string" is a mess, not a valid JSON string...

Comment: sorry my mistake typo :( now edited

Comment: Still, `{"authority":"decoded":"com.android.contacts","encoded"` is not a valid JSON fragment, JSON Object also should begin with `{`. Paste your JSON string into [this validator](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and you'll see errors you have.

Comment: Is it okay now? Actually its just part of an json string. I am sure that string is being generated correctly because its not getting generated manually its coming from method "toJson" of Gson class

Comment: Please edit your question to include the **exact** output from printing out histroyDataObject.getString("targetIntent"). Also, include the definition of your *Intent* class.

Comment: Hey I also tagged it as android and Intent is defined for Android. So I don't think that I should include definition of Intent class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet is `Intent#uriString` is of type `android.net.Uri` which has no no-arg public constructor. I means you have to write `JsonDeserializer<Uri>` like this:

```
public class UriDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Uri> {
  @Override
  public Uri deserialize(final JsonElement src, final Type srcType,
      final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    return Uri.parse(src.getAsString());
  }
}
```

and then register it via `GsonBuilder`:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Uri.class, new UriDeserializer())
    .create();
```

EDIT:

You have to register custom adapters in case any property doesn't define public no-arg constructor. You may read more in [Gson docs - Custom Serialization and Deserialization](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization).

Comment: Can you please elaborate it why we are doing this? I think its working but let me check completely then I'll accept it :)

Comment: But it's omitting lot of data after again conversion from object to json string I am getting something like:
{"targetIntent":{
            "mAction":"android.intent.action.VIEW",
            "mData":{

            },
            "mFlags":0
         }}

Comment: "from object to json string" is the other way (`gson.toJson(Intent)`) - you asked about `gson.fromJson(String)` here, that's not the same issue.

Comment: yes but if I convert again object to json using gson.toJson then it should give the same strig. Isn't?
And if I am using src.getAsString() it gives exception like:
08-31 02:25:22.274: W/System.err(2946): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject

I change src.getAsString() to src.toString().

Comment: `UriDeserializer` deserializes, while you're trying to **serialize** `Intent` object to JSON, to you should register `JsonSerializer<Uri>` also, which will return `new JsonPrimitive(src.toString());`.

Comment: ...plus - since comments are getting too long and you resolved your original problem from question - I suggest to finish EOT here and ask new question if you have another problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with android development however when looking at the source code of android.net.Uri class http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/net/Uri.java/?v=source I see that it is an abstract class. So this is probably the main reason why it fails.
To make it work you would need to write a custom TypeAdapter and use the parse method for android URI class.

You can also have a look at Genson library http://code.google.com/p/genson/. It has nice features and performances. In addition it weights as much as gson (200K).
An example with Genson for your problem:

```
class AndroidURIDeserializer implements Deserializer<Uri> {
    public Uri deserialize(ObjectReader reader, Context ctx) throws TransformationException,
            IOException {
        return Uri.parse(reader.valueAsString());
    }
}

Genson genson = new Genson.Builder().withDeserializers(new AndroidURIDeserializer()).create();
Intent pojo = genson.deserialize(json, Intent.class);
```

Comment: Yes I used serializer and deserializer for the same. But I have to accept above answer because he replied first but appreciate your effort too thanks!!